# Dynamic data load by ajax in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have `Post` show method where i show each post by their `id` and this is how it's look like:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$comments = Comment::where('post_id', '=', $post->id)->get();
return view('single', compact('post','comments'));
```

with this i can basically load my post details and foreach that post comments (so far so good).

#### What I want to do

Is to get my comments by ajax, so for example when `user 1` is reading the post and somewhere else `user 2` add new comment `user 1` see it imminently. So `user 1` doesn't need to refresh the page to see the new comment.

## Question

How can I do that?

Comment: For something like this you could use either use a method called long polling (basically make an ajax request every few seconds and then check to see if a new one has arrived) or you could look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting

Comment: @RossWilson i really prefer to handle everything in my own application rather than share data to third-party such as pusher etc. can be that happen? `PS` calling database every seconds will destroy my app speed and...

Comment: @mafortis as ross mentioned you can use the build in Laravel Broadcasting, this also works with socket.io, which you can run on your own servers.

Comment: @RobinDirksen just to be clear, when i use socket.io I also should use echo based on laravel docs, then am I forced to use vue for handling all these JavaScript codes in my app? (i know it might be silly question but i need to know before install them on my app :) )

Comment: @mafortis so far I know, you can also set it up in javascript without using vue.js. The only thing is that you need to run your own socket.io server.

Comment: @RobinDirksen you sound it impossible :), is that hard?

Comment: @RobinDirksen you sound it impossible :), is that hard?

Comment: It isn't as simple as long polling, however, there are plenty of posts/tutorials on how to set up socket.io depending on you requirements and server setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use channels of Laravel combined to redis server. Each time you store a comment you can push to the post channel your comment and display it with ajax (use laravel echo server). All subscribed users to this channel will receive the new comment.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, just for clarify about `All subscribed users` does this need to user be registered? because all i need is to fresh blade with new data regardless person behind monitor is user or just visitor.

Comment: @mafortis no, every visitor to your website can subscribe to a channel. You can setup authentication for specific posts where only authenticated users have permissions for. This can be setup by using a PrivateChannel which will check for the permissions in `routes/channels.php`.

Comment: No, you can subscribe public visitor or authenticated user: the channel can be public or not.Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events

Comment: @Yebor974 thanks man, for the last question, when i run broadcasting what will happen to my controller function? I mean should i change my function or how? how exactly new data will pass to my blade?

Comment: When you store your comment in controller you need to broadcast your event, for example :

`broadcast(new NewWallCommentEvent($wallComment));`

Next when your event is excecuting, your clients will received the serialized comment object.

Comment: @Yebor974 i'm aware of that, i should add `event()` after `$comment->save();` what i wanted to know how would it appear to my blade?

Comment: @mafortis OK. To load in blade you need to use laravel-echo-server. In my code, i use for example this :

`window.Echo.channel('Wall.{{ class_basename(get_class($object)) }}.{{ $object->id }}')
    .listen('Wall\\NewWallMessage', function (e) {
        var wallMessageTemplate = $.templates('#wall-message-template');
        $(document).find('.wall_messages_list > 
           .wall_messages').prepend(wallMessageTemplate.render(e.wall));
});`

where $object is my post and e.wall is my comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do this

PHP

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}/comments', 'PostsController@comments');

public function post(Post $post) {
    return response()->json(
        Post::with('comments')->get()   // Create HasMany relation named "comments", see Eloquent Relationships
    );
}
```

Javascript

```
(function($) {
    var intervalMiliseconds = 5000;
    var pool = function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/post/100/comments',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    };

    setInterval(pool, intervalMiliseconds);
})(jQuery);
```

Please avoid using PHP code in your javascript code, simply move all JS code to `*.js` files, and most if not all the required data from PHP pass by using `data-*` element attributes

Comment: i will try this, thanks. anyway, as this code should i append my data to my view? should i delete my `comments` foreach?

Comment: Since you load this data in ajax-way you can do this if you want, it's optional *to not* use PHP-generated data while using ajax data loading. Remember that mixing ajax with content generated by php is sometimes painful to understand, on example if you conditionally append a script that dynamically loads something else